# Typescript & Express: Export several routes from single index.ts file to prefix with ''/api/v1"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to tidy up my routes. I would like to have 1 file,index.ts, to export all my routes from. I have seen something similar done in plain JavaScript but not sure on the syntax in typescript.

```
The error I get is: TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
```

(old but works)BaseRoutes.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';
import {PostRoutes} from '../PostRoutes';
import {CspRoutes} from '../CspRoutes';
import {CustomerPreferenceRoutes} from '../CustomerPreferenceRoutes';
import { SalesOrderRoutes } from '../SalesOrderRoutes';
let app = express();
const BASE_API: string = '/api/v2';
class BaseRoutes{
    get routes(){
        app.use(BASE_API, new PostRoutes().routes);
        app.use(BASE_API, new CspRoutes().routes);
        app.use(BASE_API, new CustomerPreferenceRoutes().routes);
        app.use(BASE_API, new SalesOrderRoutes().routes);
        return app;
    }
}
export {BaseRoutes}
```

(new does not work)BaseRoutes.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';

let routes = require('../index');
let app = express();
const BASE_API: string = '/api/v2';

class BaseRoutes{
    get routes(){
        app.use(BASE_API,routes);
        return app;
    }
}
export {BaseRoutes}
```

PostRoutes.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';
import {PostController} from '../../controllers/PostController'

let router = express.Router();

class PostRoutes{
    private _postController:PostController;
    constructor(){
        this._postController = new PostController();
    }
    get routes(){
        let controller = this._postController
        router.get('/posts',controller.retrieve)
        router.get('/posts/:_id',controller.findById)
        return router;
    }
}
export{PostRoutes};
```

index.ts

```
export * from './PostRoutes';
export * from './SalesOrderRoutes';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you messed up your imports.

```
export * from './PostRoutes';
export * from './SalesOrderRoutes';
```

You are re-exporting all the exports from `PostRoutes` and `SalesOrderRoutes` etc. , so when you finally import it in `BaseRoutes` , you actually import all the constructors you exported in each route.

What you want to do is:

```
import { PostRoutes, SalesOrderRoutes } from '../index';
```

And then use() each route explicitly.

Edit: You can read more about [Typescript modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) and [Javascript modules](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

---

Comment: That does clean up things. However is the a way to do something like this 
app.use('/api/v1', require('../routes/v1')); like in javascript?

Comment: Yes, but then '../routes/v1' module needs to return router object, so that, when module is imported you end up with app.use('api/v1', routerImportedFromAnotherModule). In other words, module '../routes/v1' needs to default export Router with routes assigned.